# How to fix Command help is already registered discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add a help command to my bot but when i run the code i get this error.

````
raise discord.ClientException('Command {0.name} is already registered.'.format(command))```
```discord.errors.ClientException: Command help is already registered.
````

Here is the code:

```
py
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="**My Commands**", description="My prefix is %", color=0xffff00)
    embedVar.add_field(name="smile", value="For when your indecisive", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="frown", value="Feel sad? Check if you can be sad!", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="live", value="Tough question for an inanimate being but ill do my best", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="die", value="LMAO", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="pain", value="pain", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="profile", value="It\'s yours", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="promote", value="hehehehe", inline=False)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`discord.py` by default has a help command, you can simply remove it with `bot.remove_command`

```py
bot.remove_command("help")
```

#### Reference:

- [`Bot.remove_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.remove_command)

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Łukasz Kwieciński's answer or directly remove the help command in the bot instance.

```
bot = commands.Bot(prefix='x', help_command=None)
```

### References:

- [Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#bot)